# orWhere with multiple conditions in Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am looking to write the following query in eloquent:

```
select * from stocks where (symbol like '%$str%' AND symbol != '$str' ) OR name like '$str%'
```

Without the last condition, it's simple:

```
$stocks = Stock::live()
        ->where('symbol','like','%'.$str.'%')
        ->where('symbol','!=',$str)
        ->get();
```

But adding `orWhere('name','like',$str.'%')` after the two `where`s returns incorrect results. Basically I am wondering how to emulate what I accomplished by using the `(condition1 AND condition2) OR condition3` syntax in the raw query above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$stocks = Stock::live()
           ->where('name', 'like' , '%'.$str.'%')
           ->orWhere(function($query) use($str) {
                $query->where('symbol','like','%'.$str.'%')
                      ->where('symbol','!=',$str); // corrected syntax 
           })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$stocks = Stock::live()->where('name', 'like' , '%'.$str.'%')
           ->orWhere(function($query) use($str) {
                $query->where('symbol','like','%'.$str.'%')
                      ->where('symbol','!=',$str) 
           })->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't test this, so sorry if it doesn't work. But I think one of these solutions could work.

```
$stocks = Stock::live()
        ->where([
            ['symbol','like','%'.$str.'%'],
            ['symbol', '!=', $str],
        ])
        ->orWhere('name','like', $str.'%')
        ->get();
```

and

```
->where(function ($query) use ($str) {
    $query->where([
            ['symbol','like','%'.$str.'%'],
            ['symbol', '!=', $str],
        ]);
})
->orWhere(function ($query) use ($str) {
    $query->where('name','like', $str.'%');
});
```